# Using SQL to deserialize datetime which was generated by C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm storing the `Datetime` into SQL Server with this code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2017-10-16 08:30:00");
byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(((DateTime)dt).ToBinary());
```

In the database, I store the `byte[]` in a `binary` column.

But how can I deserialize this binary data back to a `DateTime` using SQL?

Comment: select convert(datetime,0x0000A80E008C1360) not worked!

Comment: in C#,the binary result is 0x003425177014d508 
in sql,the binary result is 0x0000A80E008C1360,use below codes:
select CONVERT(varbinary(8),convert(datetime,'2017-10-16 08:30'))
How can they be converted to each other?

Comment: Can you not simply use a `DateTime` column in the database?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If something looks like a `DATETIME`, smells like a `DATETIME` and behaves like a `DATETIME`, then it  ***IS*** a `DATETIME` and should be stored as such - as a `DATETIME` (or possibly `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)`) - but most **certainly NOT** as a binary!

Comment: Thank you for your reply！
I'm design a general column with type of binary which can store multiple formats of data like DateTime、Int、decimal、String.
but when i use these code "BitConverter.GetBytes(((DateTime)dt).ToBinary())" to generate datetime to binary and store in database,
i can't deserialize it in sql use "select convert(datetime,0x0000A80E008C1360)"
my question is how can i deserialize it in sql server?

Comment: It sounds like your program is suffering from the [inner-platform effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect). If your SQL server code knows that the data is a datetime, and needs to access it in that format, just store it as a `datetime`. What is the problem you are trying to solve with a "general column which can store multiple formats"? There's probably a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are storing it as a number (you can use MS SQL's `datetime`), but if you need to then I suggest storing seconds (unix timestamp aka epoch) (or ticks if you want to be very precise).

Comment: Thank you for your reply！
I'm design a general column with type of binary which can store multiple formats of data like DateTime、Int、decimal、String.
but when i use these code "BitConverter.GetBytes(((DateTime)dt).ToBinary())" to generate datetime to binary and store in database,
i can't deserialize it in sql use "select convert(datetime,0x0000A80E008C1360)"
my question is how can i deserialize it in sql server?